# Match rows from two dataframes with closest values

Tags: r, match

Hope anyone can assist me with this one. I am working on measuring branches. I have two datasets: `df.ref`(reference) and `df.tst` (modelled). The reference states that there are three branches `df.ref$ID` with values for width and length for each branch.

```
df.ref <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3))
df.ref$length <- c(1.3,1.8,2.3)
df.ref$width <- c(0.5,0.7,0.9)
df.ref
```

The `df.tst` contains modelled measurements of the same three branches. However, there are more branches, six `df.tst$ID` with values for length and width as well.

```
df.tst <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df.tst$length <- c(1.1,1.5,1.8,1.8,2.1,2.6)
df.tst$width <- c(0.6,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.8,1.0)
df.tst
```

I would like to match the closest value from modelled to reference using the values from length and width within a threshold (0.2 for example). Results could be like this:

```
results <- data.frame(ID.ref=c(1,2,3))
results$ID.tst.match <- c(1,3,5)
results
```

I tried using find.matches, but results were not as expected. I was also thinking of using RMSE to see the minimum RMSE for each row, and getting iterative, but there must be a cleaner solution.

Also, there might be the case that there is no solution (beyond the threshold).
Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi. I am looking into the row in `df.tst` which is closest to any row in `df.ref`. row1 is closest (by diff) to the ref value than row2 within the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use would be to measure all pairwise euclidean distances between the data points using the [dist](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html) function:

```
> dist_mat <- as.matrix(dist(combined[,c('length', 'width')]))
> dist_mat
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
1 0.0000000 0.4000000 0.7071068 0.7615773 1.0198039 1.5524175 0.2236068 0.7071068 1.2369317
2 0.4000000 0.0000000 0.3162278 0.4242641 0.6324555 1.1704700 0.2236068 0.3162278 0.8544004
3 0.7071068 0.3162278 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.3162278 0.8544004 0.5385165 0.0000000 0.5385165
4 0.7615773 0.4242641 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.3162278 0.8062258 0.6403124 0.2000000 0.5000000
5 1.0198039 0.6324555 0.3162278 0.3162278 0.0000000 0.5385165 0.8544004 0.3162278 0.2236068
6 1.5524175 1.1704700 0.8544004 0.8062258 0.5385165 0.0000000 1.3928388 0.8544004 0.3162278
7 0.2236068 0.2236068 0.5385165 0.6403124 0.8544004 1.3928388 0.0000000 0.5385165 1.0770330
8 0.7071068 0.3162278 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.3162278 0.8544004 0.5385165 0.0000000 0.5385165
9 1.2369317 0.8544004 0.5385165 0.5000000 0.2236068 0.3162278 1.0770330 0.5385165 0.0000000
```

Since this includes both within data frame and across data frame comparisons, you can then extract only those distance between elements in the different data frames:

```
> type_ind <- combined$type == 'test'
> type_ind
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> cross_comparisons <- dist_mat[type_ind, !type_ind]
> rownames(cross_comparisons) <- df.tst$ID
> colnames(cross_comparisons) <- df.ref$ID
> cross_comparisons
          1         2         3
1 0.2236068 0.7071068 1.2369317
2 0.2236068 0.3162278 0.8544004
3 0.5385165 0.0000000 0.5385165
4 0.6403124 0.2000000 0.5000000
5 0.8544004 0.3162278 0.2236068
6 1.3928388 0.8544004 0.3162278
```

Next, to determine the closest point for each of the three reference data points, you simply find the minimum value in each column:

```
> apply(cross_comparisons, 2, which.min)
1 2 3 
1 3 5
```

And to check whether the distance is within your threshold you can do:

```
> threshold <- 0.2
> apply(cross_comparisons, 2, function(x) { any(x < threshold) })
    1     2     3 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!